# Что означет здесь «Ну, держись!»?

Tags: фраза

Герои фильма бросают (с испуга) шишками в говорящего коня и старик кричит: «Ну держись!». Что это означает в этом контексте?

Он тоже там кричит что-то похожее на «Ну, держись!» (12:47), но я не смог расслышать что именно.

Ссылка на фильм «Алёша Попович и Тугарин Змей» на YouTube, смотрите, пожалуйста, с 12:46 до 12:55: https://youtube.com/watch?v=8vPQKM5UOJU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фраза "Ну, держись!" означает "берегись, сейчас ты у меня получишь" или что-то в этом роде. ("Watch out. I'm gonna get you!").

На 12:47 он говорит что-то невразумительное, похожее на "Ян Креститель".

Comment: Вот сразу после "Иоанн Креститель" он и кричит снова "ну, держись"

Comment: @ spbnative Почему снова? В отрезке 12:46 по 12:55 это в первый раз.

Comment: Хорошо, не снова, а в первый раз. Я оговорился. Просто по Вашему комментарию показалось, что вы вообще не слышали, что там было "ну, держись"